# Model Binding null versus User given null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, model-binding

I am fairly new to .net core c# and wanted to know the following.
Whenever we put thru a HTTPRequest with body, c# model binding binds the same to a complex object (in my case). But in cases, where the the body did not have certain attributes populated, the model binding marks those as null. But in some cases, the user might populate it as null. I want to differentiate this and depending upon the same, I want to know whether I can overwrite what is already present in DB. Or I can read from Db, merge with the new request and then write again. Please let me know if there is a way to approach this problem, thanks :)

Example

```
[HttpPut] 
public HttpResponseMessage PutAlbum(Album album)
{
}

Album
{
   public int songs;
   public string name;
   public string composer;
   .
   .
}
```

Request

```
Req 1
{
   songs = 2,
   name = "xyz"
}

Req 2
{
   songs = 2,
   name = "xyz"
   composer = null
}
```

In Req1, model binding assigns to null. Whereas in Req2, the user assigns composer to null. Is there a easy and optimal way to differentiate the same ??

Comment: In Req-1, the `compusr` is `null` while in Req-2, the `compuser` will have a `null as string value`.

Comment: Have the UI send something else like empty string if it's important to distinguish between "was not sent" and "was sent as ..".

Comment: You're in charge of what meanings to ascribe to stuff, and you can send more props if you need. You don't have to try and pack "set composer to"/"remove composer"/"ignore composer"/"append composer"/"etc etc" all into a single field

Comment: Side note, popular json serializers either provide a way of handling case differences in json vs c# or they provide an attribute that allows you to declare what j prop should be mapped to what c# prop so you don't have to violate c# naming conventions by camel casing all your public props..

Comment: I think in C# you won't be able to tell the difference. In JS you would have undefined and null, but in C# you only have null/default value for types.

Comment: How about setting a default value in your model? For example `public string composer { get; set; } = "none";` ?